# How to implement <IEnumerable> for custom queue?

Tags: c#

I have a custom queue class that is implemented via linked list, but I can't figure out how ot implement IEnumerable for something that is not array.

It's easy to implement it using Dequeue(), but I don't want enumeration to mutate my collection.

Here is my code for DQueue class:

```
class DQueue<Item> : IEnumerable<Item>
    {
        private Node<Item> startNode;
        private Node<Item> lastNode;
        private int _size;

        public DQueue()
        {
            _size = 0;
        }

        public void Enqueue(Item item)
        {
            _size++;
            if (startNode == null) {
                startNode = new Node<Item>();
                startNode.data = item;
                lastNode = startNode;
            } else {
                Node<Item> temp = new Node<Item>();
                temp.data = item;
                lastNode.next = temp;
                lastNode = temp;
            }
        }

        public Item Dequeue()
        {
            Item temp = startNode.data;
            startNode = startNode.next;
            _size--;
            return temp;
        }

        public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return startNode == null;
        }

        public int Size()
        {
            return _size;
        }


        private class Node<InnerItem>
        {
            public InnerItem data;
            public Node<InnerItem> next;

            public Node()
            {
                next = null;
            }
        }

        // IEnumerable
        public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Node<Item> current;

            for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
                //yield return values[i];
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How *would* you iterate over the linked list? You can write the same code,  but after retrieving an item " return"it with yield return. Eg `var current=startNode;while(current!=null){yield return current;current=current.next;}`. Or `for(var current=startNode;current!=null;current=current.next){yield return current;}`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos doesnt this reset the element to first each iteration? Or does yield remembers and doesnt do that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos coming from other languages yield looks like magic

Comment: `yield` isn't the same as `return`. The compiler generates a state machine that returns the next `step` each time someone calls `MoveNext` in the enumerator.

Comment: @Dvole `yield return` has some magic to it. Imagine little dwarfs turning a wheel. Each time you instruct them (call `MoveNext()`) they turn the wheel, putting in place the next value. It's a simple iterator done on your behalf by the compiler

Answer (score 1):

Suggest next solve, iteration from start node:

```
public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
        {
                for (Node<Item> item = startNode; item != null; item = item.next)
                {
                    yield return item.data;
                }
        }
```

Comment: @RowlandShaw can you more describe your things?

Comment: @RowlandShaw It is perfectly valid to use `yield return` in GetEnumerator().  The compiler takes care of creating the IEnumerator instance.